# How to get ReactPHP to listen to any available port/socket through Vagrant?

Tags: php, vagrant

- I am trying to run [ReactPHP](http://reactphp.org/) through a Vagrant Box.
- I am having problems accessing port 8080 through the host machine

  - This causes me to get an http-not-found, or a websocket onclose (1006) error.
- I **am** able to: `$ telnet 127.0.0.1 8080` with the service running.
- I **am not** able to access `http://192.168.33.10:8080`

I've tried updating my Vagrantfile with:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 8080
..
$ vagrant halt && vagrant up
```

This is the code exactly from ReactPHP *(I just tried different ports)*:

```
    $app = function ($request, $response) {
        $response->writeHead(200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/plain'));
        $response->end("Hello World\n");
    };

    $loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
    $socket = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
    $http = new React\Http\Server($socket, $loop);

    $http->on('request', $app);
    echo "Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080\n";

    $socket->listen(8080);
    $loop->run();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is access an application which is not exposed to the network. Your ReactPHP is only accessible from inside the vm (127.0.0.1), which is why you can access it from the inside of your vagrant vm but not from the outside.

You can make your app reachable from your network in many different ways:

**Port forwarding**

You already took the first step for port forwarding in that you added this to your Vagrantfile (btw., there is `vagrant reload` which does `vagrant halt` and `vagrant up`). Now, if you access `http://localhost:8080` from your host it should forward this request into your vm to port 8080. This should work without any further changes.

**Binding to 0.0.0.0**

You can try to tell ReactPHP to bind to 0.0.0.0 which means the app is exposed to the network. This means you don't need any port forwarding and can access the app through `http://{VM_IP}:8080`.

**Using a webserver**

In a production environment, you'd use a webserver like apache/nginx to expose your app to the internet. The webserver would listen on port 80 and route traffic for different domains to apps running internally on different ports.